# Node.js assert library vs. other assert libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, assert

According to node.js assert library [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html):

> The module is intended for internal use by Node.js, but can be used in
>   application code via require('assert'). However, assert is not a
>   testing framework, and is not intended to be used as a general purpose
>   assertion library.

I was looking at [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) as an alternative assert library (no BDD API, only the assert API), and at the end I see that the assert functionality is very similar.

Why Chai's assert library is a better assert library? It does everything than node.js does (beside being just more rich in terms of assertion available, but that's just syntactic sugar-coating). Even simple things like the total count of assert executed is not available on both.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: They have stated it very clearly - `assert` is **not** a testing framework, while `chai` **is**. `"beside being just more rich in terms of assertion available"`. You are asking what's the difference between a car and a bicycle. Yes, **parts** of them might be similar, but their purpose is totally different. If you simply need to check something - use `assert`. If you are doing tests - use `chai` or something similar.

Comment: node.js: assert.equal(a, 5)
chai: asser.equal(a, 5)
what's the difference. I would not compare a bicycle with a car. I would instead compare a cheap car and a luxury one. They both take you there, one with style :)

Comment: I also don't understand why the Node `assert` module docs say not to use it as a general purpose assertion library.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

UPDATE (April 2017): Node.js no longer warns people away from using `assert` so the answer below is now outdated. Leaving it for historical interest, though.

Here's [the answer I posted to a very similar question on the Node.js issue tracker](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5312#issuecomment-244282781).

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4532 and other issues allude to the reason the documentation recommends against using `assert` for unit testing: There are edge case bugs (or at least certainly surprises) and missing features.

A little more context: Knowing what we now know, if we were designing/building Node.js core all over again, the `assert` module would either not exist in Node.js or else consist of far fewer functions--quite possibly just `assert()` (which is currently an alias for `assert.ok()`).

The reasons for this, at least from my perspective, are:

- all the stuff being done in `assert` could easily be done in userland
- core efforts are better spent elsewhere than perfecting a unit testing module that can be done in userland

There's additional context that others may choose to add here or not (such as why, all things being equal, we would favor keeping core small and doing things in userland). But that's the so-called 30,000 foot view.

Since `assert` has been in Node.js for a long time and a lot of the ecosystem depends on it, we are unlikely (at least as best as I can tell at the current time) to ever remove `assert.throws()` and friends. It would break too much stuff. But we can discourage people from using `assert` and encourage them to use userland modules that are maintained by people who care deeply about them and who aggressively fix edge-case bugs and who add cool new features when it makes sense. So that's what that's all about.

True, if you're doing straightforward assertions with simple cases, `assert` probably will meet your needs. But if you ever outgrow `assert`, you'll be better off with `chai` or whatever. So we encourage people to start there. It's better for them (usually) and better for us (usually).

I hope this is helpful and answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Trott! I understand also the limitation of the assert() in node.js. In fact in my project I ended up using chai as assert library in userland, and I'm quite happy with it.

Answer (score 8):

I guess since nobody gave me any good feedback I'll try to provide some light on my original question after some time of working with both node.js assert and chai's assert.

The answer at the very end is that functionality-wise they are the same. The only reason why chai's assert exist is so if you read the code you can get a better understanding of the tests, but that's about it.

For example, testing for a null value with Node.js:

> assert(foo === null);

And using chai:

> assert.isNull(foo);

They are perfectly equivalent, and sticking to node.js assert limits your dependency list.

Comment: I would disagree that Chai get's you a better understanding of your code. You need to learn yet-another-javascript-library to use it. True or False is as easy as it gets, for this reason I would recommend people to stay away from Chai for the sake of readability of code.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer: I am the author of the [assertthat](https://github.com/thenativeweb/assertthat) module that I will refer to in this answer.**

Basically, you can achieve all the things with Node's very own `assert` module that you can do with all the other modules out there, such as [Should.js](https://shouldjs.github.io/), [expect.js](https://github.com/Automattic/expect.js) or [assertthat](https://github.com/thenativeweb/assertthat). Their main difference is the way of how you can express your intent.

Semantically speaking, the following lines of code are all equivalent to each other:

```
assert.areEqual(foo, bar);
foo.should.be.equal(bar);
expect(foo).to.be(bar);
assert.that(foo).is.EqualTo(bar);
```

Syntactically, there are two major differences:

First, the `should` syntax only works if `foo` is not equal to `null` or `undefined`, hence it's inferior to the other ones. Second, there is a difference in readability: While `assert.that(...)` reads like natural language, all the others don't.

After all, Chai is only a wrapper around a few assertion modules to make things easier for you.

So, to cut a long story short: No, there is no technical reason why to prefer one over the other, but readability and `null` compatibility may be reasons.

I hope this helps :-)

PS: Of course, internally, they may be implemented differently, so there may be subtle things e.g., how equality is checked. As said in the disclaimer, I'm the author of assertthat so I may be biased, but in the last few years I had the situation from time to time where assertthat was more reliable than the other ones, but as said, I may be biased.

Answer (score 2):

Since noone mentioned it, I thought I would mention rockstar programmer [Guillermo Rauch's article](http://web.archive.org/web/20151214200717/http://www.devthought.com:80/2014/02/26/the-modular-approach-to-testing) (link is to Web Archive backup) on why you should avoid expect-style frameworks in favor of plainer `assert` style testing.

Mind you, he is the author of `expect.js`, so he has once thought otherwise. So have I.

He makes an elaborate argument, but basically it's about reducing the mental burden of API overload. I can *never* remember which dialect of should and expect I am writing. Was it `.includes(foo).to.be.true()` or was it `.includes(foo).to.be.true` or was it ...

TJ Holowaychuck wrote a nice assert library called `better-assert` to get better output [which you might check out](https://github.com/tj/better-assert).